# How to specify element in foreach loop to a variable?

Tags: perl

I use below Perl code, and want to add specific `$i` in foreach into variable `$targetBank` and `$targetEntry`.

For 1_Target Bank & 1_Target Entry they are ok to print out.

But for 2_Target Bank & 2_Target Entry they are not working.

It seems the `$targetBank` and `$targetEntry` variable refresh every time in the foreach loop.

How should I modify my code?

```
my @SPLIT =split /\./, $longSentense;
foreach my $i (@SPLIT)
{
    if($i =~ /u_b.*/)
    {
        my $targetBank=$i;
        print "1_Target Bank= $targetBank\n";
    }
    elsif ($i =~ /g_tq.*/)
    {
        my $targetEntry=$i;
        print "1_Target Entry= $targetEntry\n";
    }
}

print  "2_Target Bank= $targetBank\n";
print  "2_Target Entry= $targetEntry\n";
```

Comment: Those variables don't exist outside of the blocks (`{...}`, under `if` and `elsif`) in which they are declared with [my](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29). If you declare them before (outside of) the loop then they will exist after the loop as well.  But, after the loop they will have the value of `$i` from the last iteration (in which they were assigned).  What do you want to store in them?

Answer (score 1):

First, always add `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of your scripts (more or that later).

A variable is only visible in the scope it was defined in. For instance, if you do:

```
{
    my $var = 42;
    print "1: $var\n";  # prints "1: 42"
}
print "2: $var\n"; # ERROR !!!
```

`$var` is visible inside the `{ ... }` block, but not after. With `use strict`, the `print "2: $var\n";` will not compile, because `$var` is not declared in this scope. Without `use strict`, this statement will work, but `$var` will be undefined.

To get this example to work, you need to declare `$var` in the same scope as `print "2: $var\n"`:

```
my $var;
{
    $var = 42;
    print "1: $var\n";  # prints "1: 42"
}
print "2: $var\n"; # prints "2: 42", as expected.
```

Note how I wrote `$var = 42` rather than `my $var = 42`: the later would declare a new variable (in this scope only), which would "shadow" the previous declaration, and, when exiting the scope (at `}`), the `$var` that would be visible would be the one declare before the block, which would still be undefined.

Also, the word "scope" is maybe a bit confusing. You can (mostly) think of a scope as "everything inside curly braces + the global scope": `if () { new scope here }`, `for (...) { new scope here }`, `sub { new scope here }`, and, everything that is not inside a block is in the global scope. Small subtlety: when you write `if (my $var = ...) { ... }` or `for my $var (...) { ... }`, it introduces 2 scopes: one with `$var`, and one inside the `{ ... }` (and they are both closed at the end of the if/for). See [this small tutorial](https://perlmaven.com/scope-of-variables-in-perl) about scopes.

Thus, your code should be:

```
use strict;   # never omit 
use warnings; # those 2 lines

my @SPLIT =split /\./, $longSentense;
my ($targetBank, $targetEntry); # Declaring your variables
foreach my $i (@SPLIT)
{
    if($i =~ /u_b/)
    {
        $targetBank=$i;
        print "1_Target Bank= $targetBank\n";
    }
    elsif ($i =~ /g_tq/)
    {
        $targetEntry=$i;
        print "1_Target Entry= $targetEntry\n";
    }
}

print  "2_Target Bank= $targetBank\n";
print  "2_Target Entry= $targetEntry\n";
```

Note that each time `$targetBank=$i;` is executed, the previous value of `$targetBank` is lost. If the condition `if($i =~ /u_b/)` is true only once in your loop, then this is not an issue. Otherwise, you might want to use an array instead of a scalar to store multiple values.

Also, as pointed out by [@TLP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp), `/u_b.*/` and `/g_tq.*/` can be simplified to `/u_b/` and `/g_tq/`.